# how do I store quantity from all items in session?

Tags: php

I'm not seeing what goes wrong here? I want to allow my users to up the quantity from an item in their shopping cart. when they press enter I want the quantity to change from 1 to the number the use rput in and I want that it calculates everything correctly. but right now it only wants to update the last item that the user changed the quantity from. how do I fix this? I thought of using a $_SESSION but that doesn't make any difference. this is part of the code

```
    <body>
<!--navbar-->
<a class="back" href="index.php"> <i class="bi bi-arrow-left-circle-fill bi-5x"></i></a>
<?php 
include "config.php";
        ?>
        <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 100px;">&#128717;</div>
        <h2 class="text-center">Winkelmandje</h2><br>
        <section class="container content-section">
            <!-- <h2 class="section-header">CART</h2> -->
            <div class="cart-row">
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>   
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">berekening</span>  
                <!-- <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">Verwijderen</span>   -->
            </div>  
            <?php
            $broodjes = $_GET['broodjes_ID'];
            
            if (isset($_SESSION['basket'])){
                if( in_array( $broodjes ,$_SESSION['basket']) )
                {
                    
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['basket'][] = $broodjes;
                    
                }
            }else{
                $_SESSION['basket'][]= $broodjes;
                
            }

         
            $sumtotal = 0;
            
                     foreach($_SESSION['basket'] as $key => $value){

                         //echo "Key = $key; value = $value; <br>";
                         $sql = "SELECT broodjes_ID, broodnaam, prijs, voorraad FROM broodjes WHERE broodjes_ID=?";
                         $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
                         $stmt->bind_param("i", $value);
                         $stmt->execute();
                         $result = $stmt->get_result();
                        
                         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                            
                            
                            echo '<div class="cart-items">';
                            echo '<div class="cart-row">';
                                echo '<div class="cart-item cart-column">';
                                    echo $row['broodnaam'];
                                echo '</div>';
                                echo '<div class="cart-item cart-column">';
                                    echo '€ ' . $row['prijs'];
                                echo '</div>';
                                //quantity
                                echo '<div class="cart-item cart-column">';
                                  echo '<form method="POST" action"">';
                                     echo '<div class="col-xs-4">';
                                     echo '<input type="hidden" name="broodnaam" id="broodnaam" value="' . $row['broodnaam'] . '">';
                                     echo '<input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="1" min="1" max="100" value="1">';
                                     echo '</div>';
                                  echo '</form>';
                                 echo '</div>';

                              //session for quantity???'
                              $_SESSION['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
                                  $quantity = 1;
                                 
                                    if (isset($_POST['quantity']) && !empty($_POST['quantity'])){
                                        $_SESSION['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
                                        
                                        if (isset($_POST['broodnaam']) && !empty($_POST['broodnaam'])){
                                             if ($_POST['broodnaam'] == $row['broodnaam']){
                                                 $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    echo '<div class="cart-item cart-column">';
                                    $rowtotaal = $row['prijs'] * $quantity;
                                    $sumtotal += $rowtotaal;
                                    echo $rowtotaal;
                                    echo '</div>';

                            echo '</div>';
                            echo '</div>';

                          
                         }
                         
                        
                     } 
                     ?> <br />
               
                    <div class="cart-total">
                        <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
                        <span class="cart-total-price"> € <?php   echo $sumtotal;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
```

and this is what it does
now situation:
[image]

[image]

how do I store the information in a session??
[image]

Comment: You seem to have one session variable called `$_SESSION['quantity']`, but individual session variables for each item ID - surely you'll need an individual quantity for each item as well? I may be misunderstanding the problem as your second image shows that it has, indeed, updated just "pants and shoes" to 2, and left the third one alone, which contrasts with you saying it only updates the last option. Can you clarify the problem, please?

Comment: no if you look in the second image you see that the price from pants hasn't updated. it's still 5.00.

Comment: and yes I guess I do but how do I make sure I get the individual quantity for each item? they are in a while loop

Comment: Until you have an individual quantity for each item in the cart, I can't see how you're getting the second display with different quantities. But, you'd need to use something like `$_SESSION['basket']['id']` and `$_SESSION['basket']['qty']` which would keep the values together in your foreach loop.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have a `while()` loop for your query results there. You call it individually for each broodjes_ID, so surely there will only be one result for each query?

Comment: I have a while loop because of the prepared statements: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/select so I can use variables like $row['broodnaam'] from the db. and how do I do a individual quantity for each item in the cart considering that it is in a foreach loop? @droopsnoot

Comment: If there's only one result, you don't need a `while()` loop, you could just use `if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ` instead. It's nothing to do with prepared statements - you can still use that, and you can (and should) use the while loop when there will be more than one result.

Comment: You'll assign the quantity to something like `$_SESSION['basket']['id']['quantity']` to have it associated with each id. Then in your `foreach` loop, just `var_dump($value)` and see what you get.